# JavaScript Array, Stack, Queue - what is the motivation behind this specific API design?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

In my day-to-day work i mostly use C# and only use javascript occasionally, so please, javascript Gurus don't judge my questions roughly!

1. Array implements the Stack by providing the `push` and `pop` method,
   but `peek` is missing, why? (yes it is trivial to implement, but still)
2. Array implements Queue but the
   operations are named `push`-`shift` or`unshift`-`pop` instead of `enqueue` and
   `dequeue`, why name them differently? Is this inspired by Python and Ruby?
3. Why APIs for Array, Stack and Queue are merged into one object, instead of segregating the interface and having different objects for that? Is it because the implementation is *cheap*?
4. Semantically in many languages (C#, C++, Java) an Array is a continuous block in memory and is not re-sizable. On the other hand, the basic collection that allows easy addition of elements is a List (ArrayList or LinkedList or the like). Would it not be better if Array was named a List in javascript?
5. How is Array implemented under the hood? Where can I find a very detailed description?

Comment: what is `peek`?

Comment: @NinaScholz, `peek` returns the last element, the same as `pop` but does not remove it from the stack.
        let stack = [];
        stack.peek = function () {
            return stack[stack.length - 1];
        };

Comment: While I don't have the answer to all of those questions, I can say that JavaScript in general tends to focus on flexibility more than anything else. Any object can be anything you want it to be depending on what methods it has. So it just seems natural for this kind of language that rather than providing multiple constructors, the same object can act like an array, a list, a queue or a stack (or any combination of them), depending on how you're using it and what you need it for.

Comment: In javascript, it's all objects, an array is basically just an object with length. Also, it's two different languages, with two very different use cases, why would everything be the same?

Comment: An array isn’t a very good queue; `shift()` and `unshift()` are usually Ө(n) on the size of the array. They aren’t “APIs for Array, Stack and Queue” either – they’re all operations you might want to perform on a list. `Array` doesn’t “implement the Stack” and doesn’t need to provide `peek()`. It’s also a pretty special type in JavaScript with how index assignment works, and the less magic, the better. (ES6 classes made it possible to extend `Array`, though.)

Comment: By the way, `shift` and `unshift` in JS aren't exactly the same as `enqueue` and `dequeue` in C#. `shift` and `unshift` both operate on the 0th index of the array, while `enqueue` adds to the end of the Queue and `dequeue` removes at the front. To use a JS array like a queue, you'd either use `unshift` and `pop` OR `push` and `shift`. (I hope I didn't get anything mixed up there.)

Comment: JS arrays are nothing more than reference type mutable objects and that's what you have. In other languages you have lists, sequences, vectors, stacks you name it. I guess in a loosely typed language like JS the array structure is chosen to provide an answer to all such needs in a simplistic manner. JS arrays let you implement an efficient solution to whatever you need within the boundaries of JS type system.

Comment: @Andii, you are absolutely right about the proper operation pairs for Queue - I've fixed my question, thank you!

Comment: @Ryan, when I say "implements", I mean "has corresponding methods that semantically do the same operation", I thought it is appropriate for javascript that is dynamically typed, with pretty loose type system, and duck-typing. In a strongly typed language like C# "implements stack" would mean - has appropriate interface and all necessary method implementations.
As for asymptotic time & space complexity, I would argue that if `shift` and `unshift` take O(N) than `pop` and `push` are probably the same. This is exactly why I'm asking for reference to implementation details

Comment: @ironstone13: No, `pop` and `push` are not the same. They’re amortized O(1) in every major engine.

Comment: @Ryan, that is very interesting! If you could provide some links that share implementation details, I would be most grateful! I am mostly interested in underlying data structures and their asymptotic performance. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. JavaScript was invented in 10 days, peek was never added since, mainly because it is easy to implement, maybe one day.
2. Differently from what you know yes
3. It is a high level programming language, also check out the Typed arrays
4. It could have been named otherwise, it is too late now.
5. It depends on the Engine, mostly like in Python

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray

Comment: 3. more importantly: its a parsed language.

Comment: @Jonasw: as opposed to…?

Comment: @Ryan theres no need to optimize datastructures, as performance is generally not in focus...

Comment: @Jonasw: What do you mean by “it’s a parsed language”? Most languages get parsed.

Comment: @Ryan but most languages get compiled / optimized in a way...  ( sorry if my definition of 'parsing' is a bit different, im not natively english speaking....)

Comment: @Jonasw: Modern JavaScript engines are optimizing and have JIT compilers.

Comment: 1. If `peek` will be added now, it will be a breaking change, I suppose

2. "Other languages" is a bit too broad - same as in Python or Ruby, different from C# and Java

3. What do you mean "high-level"? Java and C# are also high level, but they have separate implementations for all of those abstract data types.

4. Agreed :-)

5. What do TypedArrays have to do with this? TypedArrays are fixed size, and they only accept ONE type. I would suspect Array implementation is very different, more similar to object, probably.

Comment: TypedArrays have a lot of common with Arrays in C, Java. By high level I mean a lot of things are abstracted away, implementation details are hidden and the APIs are powerful.

Comment: Yes, TypedArrays are very similar to Arrays in C# and Java, and I already know how that works. I'm mainly interested in implementation for Array in javascript (not TypedArray)